# Visual Studio 2012 Vb.net cannot switch configuration to release mode

Tags: vb.net, debugging, release

I created a **VS Studio 2012** WSP project for a web site written in vb.net.

I am trying to publish, but the only release option available is debug mode.  I never had this problem with 2008, so I'm not sure what to do.  I went to property pages and I see where I can add a new configuration, but from what I read in articles, I'm supposed to have a release mode already there.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, since no one answered this and I eventually figured out what my problem was, I'll say so here.  I was running a WSP application.  I converted it to WAP and all works great now.

If I can help just ONE person with this answer, I'll be happy :)